# Problem with mongoose schema reference in Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm new to Node, Mongoose and to everything related to Backend. I ran into a problem recently. I couldn't figure it out as the same code in exercise files of a development course seems to be the same. Nevertheless problem still doesn't resolve. Thing I'm trying to do, coding along with the tutorials, is that I want to define a Mongoose model for comments in the Mongo database for every campground section that I have displayed on the page. I have models folder where I define models for campground and comments, a seeds.js file where I dynamically add data to campgrounds (in order for it to appear with comments instantly) and then add comments. Here is what the actual code looks like for these files:
 app.js-->

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Campground=require("./models/campground");
var seedDB = require("./seeds");
var PORT = process.env.IP || 3200;

seedDB();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/yelp_camp', { useNewUrlParser: true }, 
(err, res) => {
if (err) throw err;
console.log('Database online');
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//schema

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
res.render("landing");

});

app.get("/campgrounds/tornike", function (req, res) {
//get all campgrounds
res.send(Campground.name);

});

app.get("/campgrounds", function (req, res) {
//get all campgrounds
Campground.find({}, function (err, camp) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.render("index", { campgrounds: camp });
    }
});

});

app.post("/campgrounds", function (req, res) {
var name = req.body.name;
var image = req.body.image;
var desc = req.body.description;
var newCampground = { name: name, image: image, description:desc };
//create new camp and save to database
Campground.create(newCampground, function (err, newlyCreated) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.redirect("/campgrounds");
    }

});

});

app.get("/campgrounds/new", function (req, res) {
res.render("new.ejs");

});

//shows more info about camp
app.get("/campgrounds/:id", function (req, res) {
//find camp with provided id 
Campground.findById(req.params.id, function (err, foundCampground) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        //render show template
        res.render("show", { campground: foundCampground });
    }
});

});


app.listen(PORT, process.env.IP, function () {
console.log("camp");
});
```

seeds.js ---->

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Campground = require("./models/campground");
var Comment = require("./models/comment");

var data = [
{
name: "something",
image: "image URL",
description: "blah blah bla1"
},

{
name: "something",
image: "image URL",
description: "blah blah bla2"
},

{
name: "something",
image: "image URL",
description: "blah blah bla3"
}
];

function seedDB() {
Campground.deleteMany({}, function(err) {
console.log("removed camps");
data.forEach(function(seed) {
  Campground.create(seed, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("added campground");
      Comment.create(
        {
          text: "dubdabdubadah",
          author: "Homer"
        },
        function(err, comment) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            campground.comments.push(comment);
            campground.save();
            console.log("Created new comment");
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
});
});
}

module.exports = seedDB;
```

comment.js --->

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");


var commentSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
text:String,
author:String
});


module.exports=mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

campground.js ---->

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
image: String,
description: String,
comments: [
{
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: "Comment"
}
]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Campground", campgroundSchema);
```

Error occurs in the seeds.js file on this line campground.comments.push(comment);
it looks like this:

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
camp
Database online
removed camps
added campground
added campground
added campground
events.js:183
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
ReferenceError: campground is not defined
```

I can't actually get my head around this one as when comparing the code to the exercise files code - it is the same. The only thing I can think of is the versions of mongoose express or something else may not be relevant or some methods deprecated, but honestly no idea what's wrong. I've been trying to solve it for several days. any idea people ?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that you haven't defined a variable named `campground`, which is correct, as you haven't.

To fix this, change `data` to `campground` in your `Campground.create` callback:

```
Campground.create(seed, function(err, campground) {
```

Comment: Thanks a million JohnnyHK !!! this callback hell is really confusing sometimes !!